# how to tell user space program to stop send? or how many characters are sent?

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I am writing a very simple tty serial driver. I have started with built-in "ARC On-Chip(fpga) UART Driver" driver. I have set tx buffer size to 4096 bytes. what happens if the user program wants to send more than 4096 bytes? in this situation I want to get 4096 byte from user and send them. I don't know how I can tell the user app that I only have sent 4096 bytes. 
I have also another question. is it possible to config a serial port to work in blocking or non-blocking mode (for transmission)?

Comment: It's done for you in very basics of UNIX, i.e. `read()` and `write()` system calls. The TTY layer provides a buffer and other means to inform user that you sent only this amount of bytes. Of course in the driver you are supposed to use TTY framework.

Comment: @0andriy thanks for comment. I am using uart_ops . the prototype of write system call is: void (*start_tx)(struct uart_port *); how can I tell the userspace app the count of sent characters? is old version of tty driver the prototype of write function was: int  (*write)(struct tty_struct * tty, const unsigned char *buf, int count);. in this function the return value shows the the count of sent characters.

Comment: TTY layer provides a circular buffer which can be accessible and the count of bytes to send can be derived from start and end pointers of the circular buffer API. Just read code of existing drivers.

Comment: I have read existing drivers many times. I know the circular buffer. suppose the size of buffer is 4096 bytes and my driver is only capable to send only 1024 byte (every time the write (f_write) is called). if user app writes more than 1024 bytes, I send only first 1024 bytes. my question is how can I tell the user app that I can not send all of them? and I have send only 1024 bytes? thanks

Comment: It is done by TTY layer transparently to the driver. A corresponding API call tells TTY layer how many bytes the driver was able to handle. User application should check the return code of `write()` system call.